# Razor reseverd words

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

That the razor syntax is neat, there's little arguing about. But i can't seem to find it anywhere...
What are the razor reserved words?
@using
@inherits
@functions
@section
Do you know any other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a list of Razor reserved keywords (**Note**: This applies to cshtml, vbhtml follows VB's rules):

### Razor-specific keywords

- inherits
- functions
- section
- helper
- model (only in MVC projects)

You can escape these using `@(inherits)`

### Language-specific Razor keywords

These are C# keywords that are understood by Razor

- if
- do
- try
- for
- foreach
- while
- switch
- lock
- using
- case
- default

You can escape them using `@(@lock)` (first `@` is used to escape the Razor parser and the second `@` is used to escape the C# parser)

### Reserved keywords

These are not reserved in RC but will be for RTM. **Update**: These will have no functionality for RTM. They are simply reserved for future use.

- namespace
- class
- layout

Answer (score 3):

You've got them all. The only one I know of that's in the RC is @model but I don't see that in the list of RazorKeywords from the source so I'm not sure how that one is used or parsed.

If you check the source file "CSharpCodeParser.cs" under the WebPages/System.Web.Razor project you'll find a list of RazorKeywords.

Comment: MVC projects effectively have their own derived code parser that adds `@model`. That's why it's not anywhere in the base code parser.

Comment: Thanks for the update marcind. I shouldn't have realized it was MVC specific. I couldn't find model in my razor parser engine either so I knew it must have been separate :)