# @Scripts not working in Web Developer for Razor

Tags: razor

Has anyone else the problem with Razor @Scripts keyword not working?

It works fine for me in Web Matrix but Web Devleoper is telling me the keyword is undefined. I checked and added all the same dependencies as Web Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `@scripts` is not a Razor keyword.

[This SO answer from MarcInd (one of the creators of Razor), lists all keywords.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340765/11492)

Comment: Okay, I did some more searching and it is mentioned in the ASP.NET web pages 2 dev preview here: http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/the-top-features-in-web-pages-2-developer-preview

The thing is, when you use the bakery template with Web Matrix, it is using the @Scripts word and works fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm marking GvS as the answer as he is right regarding WebMatrix 1. I hope support will be added to VS later on after version 2 is out of beta.

Comment: I see, it's not a keyword as far as I can see, it is a property of the page in that specific version.