# Using a item which name is "class"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to know how to solve the following problem:

I have a razor view with the following code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyItems)
{
    <option value="@item.id">@item.class</option>
}
```

the problem, I get the message:

> "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.
>   An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.

how to avoid this? The MyItem Class has a element named "class" and I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338627/razor-reseverd-words

Comment: How did you managed to write a property with name "class". Was the compiler happy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the @ character in front of the reserved word:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyItems)
{
     <option value="@item.id">@(item.@class)</option>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reserved words is possible if they are escaped like this: `@(class)`

There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338627/razor-reseverd-words) listing all these words.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, but my solution was to remove a closing razor comment tag `*@` that got left behind without a matching open tag.

This was in an ASP.NET MVC Razor view.