# strongly typed helpers inside @model IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Why am I not able to use strongly typed helpers in the code below?

```
@using ISApplication.Models
@model IEnumerable<PersonInformation>

@foreach (PersonInformation item in Model)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) // Error here.
    @item.Name // But this line is ok

    @* and so on... *@
}
```

The error message is

`The type of arguments for method '...LabelFor<>... ' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried going @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) , I think model maybe a razor reserved word you can't use here..

Comment: I tried that without success. After I type `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.` I get IntelliSense autocomplete for `Aggregate<>, All<>, Any<>, AsEnumerable<>`, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to pass item to your lambda? Like @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Name)

Comment: See answer for both - you need to index into your IEnumerable

Comment: @NunoCarmo I tried that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this way. You need to access the Name from the item.

```
@foreach (PersonInformation item in Model)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Name); 
    @Html.DisplayFor(x =>item.Name)

}
```

Comment: Beware for future reference - this will work but will not produce the required naming convention of MVC for the input controls, so when posting back any values, they will not be parsed into the correct properties (likely to come through as null)

Comment: @m.t.bennett I agree with you.. You statement is perfectly valid if OP has Input fields, but for display fields(they are anyways not posted back) this should be fine.

Comment: Agreed - I just wanted to add the footnote for anyone stumbling across this and were unaware :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I know what your trying to do.

First of all it would seem that the model parameter you are using in your lambda expression is a [razor reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338627/razor-reseverd-words) - this is what is causing your type error.

secondly, to solve your enumerable problem, to get both label and value coming out you will have to use the index of the value in the IEnumerable

for example:

```
@using ISApplication.Models
@model IEnumerable<PersonInformation>
@
{
  List<PersonalInformation> people = Model.ToList();
  int i = 0;
}
@foreach (PersonInformation item in people)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => people[i].Name) // Error here.
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => people[i].Name) // But this line is ok

    @* and so on... *@
    i++;
}
```

EDIT:

This method is with just a for loop, as currently there is no need to enumerate the collection

```
@using ISApplication.Models
@model IEnumerable<PersonInformation>
@
{
  List<PersonalInformation> people = Model.ToList();
}
@for(int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => people[i].Name) // Error here.
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => people[i].Name) // But this line is ok

    @* and so on... *@
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do this I get an error on `m[i]` saying `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ISApplication.Models.PersonInformation>'`.

Comment: I though using `model => model.Property` inside the strongly typed helpers was ok because VS 2012 uses this syntax on its automatically generated Views (when you create a controller with scaffolding based on a model). The code was working before, I only started having problems when I put `IEnumerable<>` in the `@model` and started using `foreach`.

Comment: I'm guessing they are interfacing with just the model itself, where as you are going deeper into the model.

Comment: I may have steered you wrong here, try replacing the m[i] with Model[i]

Comment: Also, you can use item.Name in the lambda expression as user @PSL points out, however it is better to index the original model, especially with input elements as they will be named correctly client side (making it ready for postback).

Comment: Trying to put index on `Model` did not do anything (I did not get any IntelliSense on that). But the following worked (assuming `i` is declared outside the `foreach` as in you code above). `@{var m = Model.ToList()[i];} @Html.LabelFor(s => m.Name);`

Comment: @m.t.bennett if you're declaring an index why not just use a `for` loop?

Comment: @Jasen yeah I was going to get to that eventually, I will edit it so that it is now a for loop, as the OP was using a foreach and I didn't know if they were going to use the inline property method in the lambda expression OR not use the DisplayFor and just pump out the value